# SSH to AWS EC2 issue - key_load_public: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, macos, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

unfortunately 3 hours of googling is not helping me on this one and I'm counting on someone out there who can walk a 'nix noob through all this.

**my situation**

I have been ssh-ing successfully into my AWS instance from my mac for months. even today it was working. this logically eliminates all the setup-related issues like making sure i have port 22 open, directing to 0.0.0.0/0, having the right username (its ubuntu not ec2-user), having my pem file correctly permissioned, etc.

then my mac hangs, i restart the mac, and suddenly i can no longer ssh. i can't even ssh in through the java client launched straight from the aws console. utilization and other status checks on the aws console look fine.

here is my -vvv with personal info replaced:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to <myip> [<myip>] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<myfilepath>/ipythonswyx1.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/<myfilepath>/ipythonswyx1.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

i figure it is fairly obvious that **debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory** is the problem here. however a) why would this suddenly stop working? b) even after i chmodded the pem file again, it is still showing this error?

the only other solution i can find online is to delete this instance and just re set up from scratch - i would very much like to keep this instance.

can you please suggest things i should google or any other diagnostics i can run? the problem with being such a n00b is i dont even know the right questions to ask or how to describe my problem other than "this thing that worked now doesnt work and i have no freaking idea why". HELP.

Comment: do you have any chance to try from another computer ? copy your key and try, this will eliminate the option keys have been corrupted

Comment: `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out` The connection is actually failing because you're not getting the version string from the remote server, which is the very beginning of the ssh protocol. The server may be malfunctioning, you may be connecting to the wrong server, or there may be a firewall interfering with the connection.

Comment: Kenster is right, you have "connection established", then your local cannot find the keys, then you *should* get "remote protocol version" (this doesn't happen).  I suspect some kind of firewall nonsense on your local Mac - as the problem happened after a restart.  You could try restarting the remote server.  You will probably need to use the advice in my answer also - as the local key on the Mac is not being found

Comment: thanks so much guys.  Frédéric, i tried connecting via putty from windows running on the same computer. still timing out. kenster - for server malfunctioning, i've restarted the instance, no avail. connecting to wrong server - i still have the same dns based on my ec2 console. @vorsprung how do i fix this "firewall nonsense on my local mac"? that sounds like the most likely problem (i can find the local key - per my reply to you below)

Comment: @swyx Have you figured it out? I have same issue. Even using my putty connection (without using ssh command from a linux server), I was not able to connect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

open a shell as your user

type this command

```
find $HOME -name ipythonswyx1.pem -print
```

This should find the path to your key.  If it doesn't there are some other possiblities:

- the key has a different name to the one shown in the the output above
- the key is under a different user account
- the key has been accidentally deleted

Assuming the key is found, note the path and use it as the parameter "identityfile" on ssh.  So, assuming that the path is /Users/Bob/.ssh/ipythonswyx1.pem and the host IP address is 54.3.4.5 then try this command

```
ssh -i /Users/Bob/.ssh/ipythonswyx1.pem ubuntu@54.3.4.5
```

If the key is not found then you need to make a new instance, detach the EBS volume from the old disk, attach the old EBS volume to the new instance, add a new key to the ".ssh/authorized_keys" file for the ubuntu user on the old EBS volume then unmount it and reattach to the old instance.

For more on this sequence of events (to change the key) see this answer on serverfault https://serverfault.com/questions/273664/how-do-i-change-the-key-pair-of-an-aws-instance-if-i-lost-my-pem-file
and in more detail with step-by-step instructions here https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598

Comment: that's just an error output.  Try searching your entire harddisk for the .pem file and if you have backups then look at them too.  If all that fails you'll have to use the EBS volume procedure